# Can someone please explain what the difference between these Sparql

Tags: sparql

I am having rdf data:

```
@prefix  foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

_:a    foaf:name   "Alice" .
_:a    foaf:knows  _:b .
_:a    foaf:knows  _:c .

_:b    foaf:name   "Bob" .

_:c    foaf:name   "Clare" .
_:c    foaf:nick   "CT" .


PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?nameX 
WHERE
 { ?x foaf:knows ?y.
 ?x  foaf:name ?nameX .
 }
```

I get a result Alice
But if I'm running this query

```
PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?nameX 
WHERE
{ ?x foaf:knows ?y.
{?x  foaf:name ?nameX .}
}
```

I am getting the same result. As I am new to Sparql please explain what is the benefit of writing ?x  foaf:name ?nameX inside {} .

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, and there is no benefit to including the extra block that you get by adding the curly braces. It's usually best to pick the simplest way to express a given query.

Comment: If I will apply filter inside the curly braces then it will be applied  to the pattern inside the {} or it will be applied to whole pattern.

Comment: FILTERs apply to the {} block.  In this case, your two forms, may yield different answers depending on the nature of the FILTER.